# Is there any solution to implement listview.builder within a single Text widget flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, sqlite, dart

```
   SizedBox(
                                        child: Padding(
                                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                                      child: Row(
                                          mainAxisAlignment:
                                              MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                          textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
                                          children: [
                                            Text(
                                              "${listData[0]['words_ar'].toString()} ",
                                              style: GoogleFonts.aclonica(
                                                  fontSize: 23.sp),
                                            ),
                                            Text(
                                              "${listData[1]['words_ar'].toString()} ",
                                              style: GoogleFonts.aclonica(
                                                  fontSize: 23.sp),
                                            ),
                                            Text(
                                              "${listData[2]['words_ar'].toString()} ",
                                              style: GoogleFonts.aclonica(
                                                  fontSize: 23.sp),
                                            ),
                                            Text(
                                              "${listData[3]['words_ar'].toString()} ",
                                              style: GoogleFonts.aclonica(
                                                  fontSize: 23.sp),
                                            ),
                                          ]),
                                    )),
```

Guys, I have SQLite data where data are in small parts, but I want to concatenate these data within a single Text widget, I can do it by providing the specific index of each value but I want to do it using listview. builder or any other method dynamically:

Suppose data:

image1
[image]

and output I want with onTap property as well:

image2
[image]

Comment: Why not concatenating it into a single String? If you can differentiate 1 verse from another then concatenate 1 verse and display it... same for vice versa

Answer (score 0):

You can use ListView as you mentioned :

```
ListView.builder(
    itemCount: listData.length,
    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
      return Text("${listData[index]['words_ar'].toString()} ",
          style: GoogleFonts.aclonica(
              fontSize: 23.sp),
          );
    },
  ),
```

Comment: I have already done it like this but this is not my question, I want to concatenate only these indexes for which (verse_id) in the SQLite table matches.